# client.get_channel(id) returning "none" on a channel that exists

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for Discord, and every time I try and send a message to a designated channel using the following code, it doesn't give me any errors, but does print "None", which I would expect when the channel doesn't exist. I have now tried this with multiple guilds/servers and multiple text channels, as well as multiple computers running the same code. In the code following, I have replaced the channelID with the int that is the channelID, and the token with my token (a string).

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'bday ', intents = intents)
channel = client.get_channel(channelID)

print(channel)

client.run("token")
```

The bot does have admin permissions, as well as both of the intent gateways

Comment: Have you invited the bot to the server where the channel with given channelID is? If not, it won't work as any other get_ function.

Comment: @langley yes I have

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to call a bot's functionality before actually running your bot.

Try to add your code inside `on_ready()` callback to ensure that you are trying to get your channel only after initializing the bot itself.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'bday ', intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
    print(channel)

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked! I've been working on that to no avail for hours now. :) I've marked your answer as accepted

Comment: is it possible to interact with a channel without having to create a bot?

Answer (score 1):

Using channelID as a integer instead of string worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify

```
client.get_channel()
```

with

```
client.get_guild(your server's id).get_channel(channel id)
```

Comment: Now it gives me the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel', so it's having the same problem finding the guild