# Discord Bot Error trying to send to a unique channel ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

when I am trying to send a message to a channel it won't work. Anyone knows why?

This here is the command I am using. This is just the code block of the not working section.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test2(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print("The Test is being started")
    Channel = config['bot']['id1']
    await Channel.send("test2")
```

And in My Config file, I have this

```
[bot]
id1= 916845047CENSORED
```

And when I try to run it I get this error:

```
The test is being started
Ignoring exception in command test2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/jp/Desktop/DISCORD BOT/bot.py", line 224, in test2
    await Channel.send("test2")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

If anyone knows how to fix this I would thank you very much

---

Edit:

The way to solve this is:

add the int to the channel ID if it is from a txt file/config

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test2(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    Channel_Id = config['bot']['id1']
    print("Test is being started")
    Chanel = bot.get_channel(int(Channel_Id))
    await Chanel.send("test2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this is:

add the int to the channel ID if it is from a txt file/config

````py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test2(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    Channel_Id = config['bot']['id1']
    print("Test is being started")
    Chanel = bot.get_channel(int(Channel_Id))
    await Chanel.send("test2")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 85 to find the line throwing the error. It's saying that the `Channel` object taken from `config['bot']['id1']` is of type `str`. You are then trying to invoke the method `.send()` on a `str` type, which it does not have.

```
...
Channel = config['bot']['id1']
await Channel.send("test2")
```

Comment: I have heard from some other people that this is the issue but how do I get it to be valid str?

Answer (score 0):

With `discord.py`, [channel objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel) are not just integers. Instead, you have to **fetch** the channel, either from a guild after fetching the guild with its id, or fetching the channel straight away. Here are some ways to do this:

```py
Channel_Id = config['bot']['id1']

# Based on your error, ensure to convert Channel_Id to an Integer
# Example: "123454" -> 123454
Channel_Id = int(Channel_Id)

# Method 1: Fetching channel straight away
Channel = bot.get_channel(Channel_id)

# Method 2: Fetching channel from guild
Guild_Id = config['bot']['GuildId'] # of course you may need to add a new config
# Remember to convert this to an Integer as well!
Guild_Id = int(Guild_Id)
Guild = bot.get_guild(Guild_Id)
Channel = Guild.get_channel(Channel_Id)

await Channel.send("Test")
```

Other helpful links:

- [`bot.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) - discord.py docs
- [`guild.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Guild.get_channel) - discord.py docs

Please note: When searching for this answer, it is recommended not to use [`bot.fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch#discord.Client.fetch_channel) as this is an API call. The above methods are recommended for general use.

---

Edit: When using `bot.get_channel` or the likes, you are likely to require **Intents**.

Links to questions like this:

- [discord.py channel returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789837/dicord-py-get-channel-returns-none)
- [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)
- [client.get_channel(id) returning "None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197394/client-get-channelid-returning-none-on-a-channel-that-exists)
- ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343781/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-send-discord-bot)

Comment: Hi sadly this didn't work I corrected my code.  I am still getting the same error

Comment: `@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test2(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    Channel_Id = config['bot']['id1']
    Guild_Id = config['bot']['gu1']
    print("Test is being started")
    Guild = bot.get_guild(Guild_Id)
    Channel = Guild.get_channel(Channel_Id)
    await Channel.send("test2")` this also doesnt work than I get this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'

Comment: Just to be sure, is both the `Channel_Id` and `Guild_Id` an integer? Or are they numbers under strings? Also check if the guild id is valid, such as by printing `Guild.name` or something similar. You can also try using Method 1 instead, as this usually works for me. @TheDEV

Comment: Tried using this  code: `Channel_Id = config['bot']['id1']
    Guild_Id = config['bot']['gu1']
    print("Test is being started")
    print("Channel ID: " + str(bot.get_channel(Channel_Id)))
    print("Guild ID: " + str(bot.get_guild(Guild_Id)))
    print("Guildname: " + str(bot.get_guild(Guild_Id).name))
    print("Chanelname: " + str(bot.get_channel(Channel_Id).name))` But from the looks of it it cant fetch the guild name or the chanel name it says none and than it says:  `NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: @TheDEV my mistake, I completely misunderstood your situation. I have noticed that this may be an issue with `Intents`. Please view the revised answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much the way to solve the problem is just to add this: `Channel_Id = (int(Channel_Id))`